# Intersection of ellipsoidal surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: analytic-geometry, surfaces, ellipsoids

Is there an explicit parametric solution describing the curve resulting from the intersection of two ellipsoidal surfaces with arbitrary position and orientation in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: generically you get an elliptic curve, so there is no rational parametrization (you could parametrize it using elliptic functions)